# Mock a method in Service for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am working on a unit test, that is how I mock:

```
  mockProxy.Setup(s => s.GetPayment(getPaymentRequest)).ReturnsAsync(getPaymentResponse);
  var sut = new FromService.Service(mockProxy.Object, mockTemplateService.Object, mockAppSettings, mockAgentRepository.Object);
        // Act
        var getBrandingResponse = await sut.GetDeliver(request);
```

this is my GetDeliver method in service:

```
 public async Task<GetDeliverResponse> GetDeliver(GetDeliverRequest request)
    {
        byte[] content = null;
        var request = new FromProxy.GetPaymentRequest()
        {
            .....
        };

        var myresponse = await proxy.GetPayment(request);
```

My problem is that although I have mocked the GetPatment method and when I debug request has value but myresponse is null, that is why the test is breaking where ever after that use the myresponse. How I can mock so myresponse bring some value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your mock to trigger in the code being tested, replace `getPaymentRequest` in the setup with `It.IsAny<PaymentRequest>()`

(Assuming your request class is called `PaymentRequest`, if not, replace `PaymentRequest` with the actual class name.)

Where you are saying 
`mockProxy.Setup(s => s.GetPayment(getPaymentRequest)).ReturnsAsync(getPaymentResponse);` the `getPaymentRequest` is a reference to a specific instance of the `PaymentRequest` class, but that instance is not the one that will be passed to your mock at runtime, the result of `new FromProxy.GetPaymentRequest()` is what will get passed. You want to use code that maps to anything of that class, not just the one instance you are currently mapping to.